# Compare 2 Files line number with row filter

Tags: bash, shell

I have 2 Files Structured like that :

```
01AAAAAAAAA
02AAAAAAAA
02AAAAAAAA
02AAAAAAAA
09AAAAAAAAA
```

I know the way to compare two row number :

```
  if (cat $fic1 | wc -l != cat $fic2 | wc -l) then
```

I want to compare the number of line 02 of the 2 files.But I don't know how filter the 02 rows .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep` is the tool to filter lines based on patterns. It can directly return a count with `-c`:

```
if (( $(grep -c '^02' $fic1) == $(grep -c '^02' $fic2) )) ; then
    echo The same number.
fi
```

Comment: @L.Quastana: The `^` means "beginning of line".